# I want add months in my aggreement end date

Tags: php, jquery, suitecrm

I have three fields one is agreement start date, month and third is agreement end date. In my suite CRM module, I want to decide agreement end date which depends on month field. Month is input number. Which user is going to enter that and also agreement start date also user going to select. e.g If agreement start date is 5/06/2018 and month is 4 then I want to set date to agreement end date is 5/10/2018. How can I do that using jquery in suite CRM?

Comment: Yes, but have you tried anything at all? Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual here - http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php - will lead you to the code below.  You really should have a read before you go any further but the code below will get you started on the path.

```
$month = 4;
$start = '5/06/2018';
$date  = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', $start );
$date->modify( "+ $month months" );
echo $date->format( 'd/m/Y' );
```